# subscript out of range error on cell reference

Tags: vba, excel

I don't understand why this has an error :

```
Dim h As String
h = Worksheets("beans").range("O11").Value.Offset(ref_count, 0)
```

`ref_count` is used in a loop, `h` is passed elsewhere in the program. I am getting a run time error 9 subscript out of range error and I don't understand why

please help me.

thanks.

Comment: range("zero one one") is not a valid cell location. Do you mean o (as in oscar) one one?

Comment: Sorry it is an "O" and I still get the same error..

Comment: Is your worksheet named "beans" ? Make sure the worksheet doesn't have a space at the beginning or end of its name (like " beans" or "beans ").  Also, you can't put .Offset after .Value, you would need to use `h = Worksheets("beans").range("o11").Offset(ref_count, 0).Value`

Comment: I think the answer really is invalid **hierarchy** of assigning *Range Object Property* as what @tigeravatar pointed out in his comment which should have been posted as answer. Yes?

Answer (score 1):

So your current code is trying to offset a value.

This is not possible.

You need to offset the range and fetch the value from this new location. You were close but not quite there.

The code should look like this:

```
Dim h As String
h = Worksheets("beans").range("o11").Offset(ref_count, 0).Value
```